# Best way to remove tokens from database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I'm developing a token based api gateway. Its basically provide a token for authentic clients. So I'm not sure how to remove expired tokens. For every request I checked whether the token is valid or not.

```
Option 1 is
Mark status of token as expired in database table row. 
and create a scheduler to run in midnight to delete expired tokens.


Option 2 is
Delete the token from the row when its expired.
In here No need to run a scheduler.
```

Normally this API Gateway will handle around 1000 requests per second and and this will increase day by day.

So I'm not sure which option I should use.

The technology I have used is. 
Spring mvc,Spring data jpa and Postgre DB. Will deploy on tomcat server.

Comment: A simple solution would be using Quartz. You can then schedule a job to run time to time removing expired tokens. Quartz also gets along well with Spring.

Comment: Option 2 is not really a solution. It's your requirement. So, what solution is left except solution 1? Why don't you put the expiration date in the token itself. No need for a database then. See https://jwt.io/

Comment: So lets say until scheduler start to run there are 1000 of tokens in database at this point program need to search the given token over 1000 records. when its increase to more token will it impact for performance ?

Comment: @JB Nizet there are situation that I need to expire tokens irrespective of expiry time.

Comment: @abc123 searching in a table of 1000 rows is a piece of cake for PostgreSQL. If you have a proper index, searching for a token in a table of millions of rows is also a piece of cake.

Comment: @JB Nizet So you suggest to not to delete each row when expire and run a scheduler to delete all the expired tokens. I'm only thinking of performance of the module.

Comment: What is a "request"? Is that a query against the database or a session? Do you use connection pooling?

Comment: @Patrick  its query against database and yes I'm using a connection pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the two options is particularly good as both will modify a table row and therefore generate I/O. At 1,000 q/s you need a better solution. On 2ndQuadrant is a [blog post on authenticating users through connection pooling](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/application-users-vs-row-level-security/) in the context of row-level security. The blog post has some issues IMHO and non-relevant material as well so I'll try to redo it here in the right way (or read my comment on the blog post over there).

In Java - as in most other programming languages and/or frameworks - connection pooling is the preferred way to connect to a database server for performance reasons. There is an implicit contract that the application requests a `Connection` instance from the pool, uses it and then returns the instance to the pool for some other thread. Holding on to a `Connection` is not an option as it breaks the pooling logic. So proceed as follows:

---

**Connection pool object**

Create a connection pool object with database cluster credentials. That role should be `GRANT`ed all necessary privileges on tables and other objects.

**Authentication**

In the application a user authenticates doing `myapp_login(username, password)` or something similar using a `Connection` from the pool. In the database the credentials are checked against a table `users` or whatever it is called in your setup. If a match is found then create a random token and insert that in a table:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE sessions (
  token      text DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()::text,
  login_time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,
  user_name  integer,
  ...
);
```

Add as many fields as you want. I use a `uuid` here (cast to `text`, read on) but you could also `md5()` some data or use some `pg_crypto` routine.

This table has to be fast so it is `UNLOGGED`. That means it is not crash-safe and will be truncated after some server error but that is not a problem: all database sessions will have been invalidated anyway. Also, do not put any constraints like `NOT NULL` on the table because the only access to this table is through the functions that you as a developer design, no ordinary user ever touches this table, and every constraint involves more CPU cycles.

The `myapp_login()` function looks somewhat like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myapp_login(uname text, password text) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
    t      text;
BEGIN
    PERFORM * FROM app_users WHERE username = uname AND pwd = password;
    IF FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO sessions(user_name) VALUES (uname) RETURNING token INTO t;
        EXECUTE format('SET SESSION "my_app.session_user" TO %s', t);
        RETURN t;
    END IF;
    SET SESSION "my_app.session_user" = '';
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT SECURITY DEFINER;
REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION myapp_login(text, text) FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION myapp_login(text, text) TO myapp_role;
```

As you can see, the `token` is also set in an environment variable with `SET SESSION` (which needs a literal text value, hence the `uuid::text` cast and the `EXECUTE` command) and then returned to the caller. That session token should be stored somewhere in your application code on the Java side.

The function does a lookup on the `app_users` table and an `INSERT` on the `sessions` table. The first is cheap, the second is expensive.

**Resume the same session for further queries**

If your app user needs further database access after the first queries, then get a `Connection` instance from the connection pool again, but don't call `myapp_ login()` but `myapp_resume(token)` instead. This latter function looks up the token in the `sessions` table (cheap) and, if found, sets the session variable to this new token. You can also check that the `login_time` value is recent or set it with the `CURRENT_TIME` to keep the session "alive" (expensive) or do any other necessary business.

The trick is to keep resuming the session as lean as possible because this is likely to be happening multiple time during a session (from the application perspective).

**Close the session**

When your app user is done, do `myapp_logout(token)` which deletes the row from the `sessions` table that corresponds to the token.

---

Sessions that are not properly closed are not deleted from the `sessions` table, but I would not worry too much about that.You could schedule a job that runs once a week to delete all rows that are older than 6 hours or so. That would also allow you to figure out where the error comes from, for instance.

A final word on the `token`. A `uuid` is just a random number, but you could also make a hash of the application user name with some random data and use that, for instance, in RLS or some other row-based access mechanism; the blog post I link to above has good info on that. In an application I have developed myself I link the row from the `users` table to what the user is allowed to see. In either case you should really weigh the pro's and con's: a hash that can be used in RLS sounds nice, but it requires the hash to be re-calculated (which tends to be expensive) and compared to the session hash on every query, a repeated lookup against a users table is also an overhead. Setting another session variable that can be checked at query time with `current_setting()` might be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be like this. When you generate token in your database, you can store time of generation. So that when client sends a request to your database, you can check if it's expired and delete it in request time.